# How to select the clicked child element within a parent element in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a parent div within which elements are added dynamically. I want to find out the class of the element which was clicked, if none of the child element was clicked but parent was clicked then I would like to get the class of parent element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').on('click', function(event) {
    // event.stopPropagation();
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>Parent//clicking here should alert parent
  <ol>
    <li class='type1'>NEW</li>//clicking on this should alert type 1
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').on('click', function(event) {
    // event.stopPropagation();
    alert($(event.target).attr('class'));
  });
});
```

this will get the **target** tag of the clicked position.

see the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf181tvq/)**

Comment: Can you explain **why** the OP should *try this*? If they didn't know how to solve the problem in the first place, how would they know what this code does?

Comment: @Arbaaz Yes, it will.